# Peer dependency issue in npm Node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, node-modules

I have run into some issues in installing the grunt related node module dependencies for my project,

I want to install the selected dependencies using one command, so I used below,

```
npm install grunt grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-cli grunt-contrib-watch grunt-exec grunt-contrib-symlink grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-copy grunt-text-replace grunt-git --save-dev
```

Got error like 'grunt-exec@0.4.6 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4 but none was installed.'
So as per the feedback from googling, found we can hardcode the dependency version like below fix,

```
npm install grunt@~0.4  grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-cli grunt-contrib-watch grunt-exec grunt-contrib-symlink grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-copy grunt-text-replace grunt-git --save-dev
```

It has temporarily fixed the issue for sometime but now I get an error like 
'grunt-git@1.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@~1.0.1 but none was installed.'

So it seems that the grunt plugins needs different version of same dependency - grunt(in my case). Installing the plugins one by one instead of a cluster also wont resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Since people want to take points away from this answer w/o reading the comments to see that a solution was found, here's what we arrived at:

An instance like this, you should review the previously released versions for `grunt-git`, find an older version that meets your reqs `(v0.3.8)` and double check if the features you want to use with the plugin are available or not. If it is, try `npm install grunt-git@0.3.8 --save-dev`. Releases can be found [here](https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-git/releases).

**Original Solution**

First you'll want to initialize your project by creating a `package.json` file by running the command `npm init`.  You'll be prompted to answer several questions, you can change the default values if you like.

Once the project has been initialized, install the dependencies one at a time & include the flag `--save` or `--save-dev`.  This will add the dependency to the package.json manifest.  Example: `npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev`

Once you have all of your dependencies listed in your package.json file, you can then achieve a one-command install using `npm install`.

The NPM registry has a [very detailed article](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json) on using `package.json` if you'd like to learn more.

Comment: I am aware how npm install works along with package.json. I beg my question might be different.

If suppose I have a package.json like below, and my grunt plugins needs different version of grunt dependency, is there any way we can mention different version dependencies.



      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.2",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.3",
        "grunt-contrib-symlink": "^0.3.0"                                                                          }

Comment: I think it's a far wiser approach to conform all your plugins to using a single version of the core grunt dependency.  Trying to manage multiple instances of grunt in a single project creates an insane amount of overhead

Comment: If you're dead set on two separate grunt instances, you'll need to maintain two separate gruntfiles and figure a way to have both versions of the dependency in `node_modules`.  You can then use the `--gruntfile` flag to specify which gruntfile should be run.  Ref: http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli

Comment: Yes you are right and thats the ideal approach I would agree to use. But the problem was grunt-exec expects exactly 0.4 version and grunt-git expects an higher version like 1.0.0

Comment: An instance like this, you should review the previously released versions for `grunt-git`, find an older version that meets your reqs (v0.3.8) and double check if the features you want to use with the plugin are available or not.  If it is, try `npm install grunt-git@0.3.8 --save-dev`.  Releases can be found here: https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-git/releases

Comment: This has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

install grunt with the global flag

```
npm install -g grunt
```

Comment: So u mean before installing the grunt plugin cluster, i need to install the grunt dependency globally?

Comment: the grunt module should be present both globally and locally

Comment: We should not mention any version of grunt when installing both globally and locally?

Comment: when you don't mention a version, it will install the latest released version

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue using the suggestions from theaccordance.

Only the recent version of grunt-git(1.0.0) was having the dependency issue, so I am installing the previous version 0.3.7 which doesn't require a particular version of grunt.

```
npm install grunt@0.4.5  grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-cli grunt-contrib-watch grunt-exec grunt-contrib-symlink grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-copy grunt-text-replace grunt-git@0.3.7 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue today when trying to install grunt-exec.

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-exec@0.4.6 wants grunt@~0.4
```

From some clues in this thread I fixed it by...

```
npm uninstall grunt
```

at the root folder of my project, and I edited package.json to remove grunt from the devDependencies.

I already had grunt installed globally, so didn't need it in the project too.

Running

> npm install -D grunt-exec

a second time worked for me and my updated devDependencies now looks like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": ">0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5"
  },
```

with the new lines being grunt, and grunt-exec.

So far my project works as it did before adding grunt-exec. It looks like I just found a simple way to downgrade to an earlier version of grunt.

Here's the version info from the global install:

```
>grunt -V
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v0.4.5
```

Hope this helps.